# Nao sei abrir o mapa na minha posicao

Tags: java, android

Depois de muita pesquisa, ainda tenho dificuldades com o java, sou novata e estou tentando aprender. Por favor me desculpe se nao consigo fazer uma pergunta clara, pois talvez eu nem saiba do que estou falando,

BOM, Por exemplo a parte de mapas que já consigo abrir, mas com uma posição de "exemplo"

e para isso estou usando o seguinte código:

```
package jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

//import java.util.concurrent.atomic.DoubleAccumulator;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;
import jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.model.Report;

import static jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.config.Constants.MAP_ZOOM;


/**
 * Created by ootaegd on 2016/12/16.
 */

public class PostPositionActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Marker marker = null;
    private LatLng locationLatLng;
    //private static final LatLng MATSUE = new LatLng(35.47222, 133.05056); //マーカ初期値
    //private LatLng locationLatLng = instantPosition;
    private float accuracy;
    //private static final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.3852243, 132.7339911);  //              izumo
    //private static final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.47222, 133.05056);      //マーカ初期値  matsue
    private String uuId;
    //private LatLng instantPosition;
    protected Realm realm;
    private TextView tvCoordinate;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_position);

        //前のactivityから渡されたデータを取得する
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        uuId = intent.getStringExtra("uuId");

        //realm設定
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

        //toolbarを設定
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.post_position_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.headPositionTitle));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        onBtnGpsClicked();
        nextViewActivity();

        //Fragment を取得
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    /**
     * 次の画面へ遷移する処理
     */
    private void nextViewActivity() {
        //位置情報ボタンを押された時の処理
        Button btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //位置情報を追加する
                addReport();

                // 画面を起動
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName("jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki", "jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.PostConfirmationActivity");
                intent.putExtra("uuId",uuId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * 現在地取得ボタンを押された時、現在地を取得する
     */
    private void onBtnGpsClicked() {
        Button btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //現在地取得
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * GoogleMapを読み込む前に、オーバライドして処理を行う
     *
     * @param googleMap
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady( GoogleMap googleMap ) {
        map = googleMap;

        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------"," original get 03");
        // final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.3852243, 132.7339911); // izumo
        // final LatLng instantPosition = new LatLng(35.47222,   133.05056);   // matsue
        locationLatLng = new LatLng(35.47222,   133.05056);   // matsue  //test
        setMarker(locationLatLng);

        // GoogleMapが押下された時の処理
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick( LatLng latLng ){
                // クリックされるたびにマーカが増えていく
                // 一つ前のマーカは削除する
                marker.remove();
                //Mapが押下されたらその位置にピンを立てる
                //緯度経度を取得
                locationLatLng = latLng;
                //ピンを立てる
                setMarker(locationLatLng);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Markerを立てる関数
     *
     * @param lacation　緯度経度情報
     */
    private void setMarker(LatLng lacation){
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(lacation)
                .title("報告場所")
                .draggable(false));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lacation, MAP_ZOOM));
    }

    /**
     * 位置情報を追加する
     * @return プライマリキー
     */
    private void addReport(){

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        //トランザクション開始
        realm.beginTransaction();

        //uuIdでターゲットを抽出
        Report report = realm.where(Report.class).equalTo("key",uuId).findFirst();
        //保存を行う
        report.setLat(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationLatLng.latitude)));
        report.setLon(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(locationLatLng.longitude)));
        report.setAccuracy(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(accuracy)));
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------", " Longitude 04 " + String.valueOf(report.getLon()));
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------", " Latitude 04 "  + String.valueOf(report.getLat()));
        Log.e("--------MESSAGE--------", " Accuracy 04 "  + String.valueOf(report.getAccuracy()));

        //トランザクション終了
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Como eu posso abrir esse mapa já na minha localização?
Acontece que peguei muitos exemplos no Google, mas, simplesmente não consigo fazer nada encaixar...

Obrigada pela ajuda e boa vontade!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usei esta lib em meu projeto. Facilitou muito.

[smart-location-lib](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib)

Está em inglês. Se tiver dificuldade, use o tradutor

[Tradutor do google](https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR)

Siga as instruções e retorne aqui com suas dúvidas.

Você também pode usar o Fused Location API do Google, mas é mais trabalhosa. 
[Tutorial Fused Location API](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API)